# What's the right approach to update a parent's component array of objects from a child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a complex form with different tabs. I use `vue-router` to switch between these and display different modular components in a `router-view` for each one of them. In these tabs I have child components with sometimes other nested child components. I use the `event bus` approach to pass data from these child components up in tree. I'm doing this because the final tab will be a summary of the form, and I will need access to all the form data. At the moment I'm using something like the below.

For example using this structure:

```
|App
--|Start
--|Question 1
  --|Answer 1
  --|Answer 2
--|Question 2
...
```

In the root component (App):

```
data() {
  return {
    questions: 0,
    answers: []
  }
},
created() {
    eventBus.$on('answer-added', answer => {
        let answer_exists = false
        this.answers.forEach( (e, i) => {
            if(e.id == answer.answer_id) answer_exists = true
        });
        if(!answer_exists) this.answers.push({
            id: answer.answer_id,
            answer: answer.answer_text
        })
    });
}
```

What's the proper way to create/update/delete the array of answers in the App component every time an event from the child is fired?
I'm sure there must be a much better way than iterating over the array elements to check whether the answer already existed or not... Just can't figure it out.

Comment: [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) is probably what you want for anything but the most simple state management.  It's created by the makers of Vue.  Instead of passing data around between components which can quickly become very hard to manage, you interact with a single global source of truth.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
if (!this.answers.find(a => a.id === answer.answer_id)) {
    this.answers.push(/* ... */);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is more or less right. There is no escape from the loop. However, there are certain things you can improve upon. Instead of `forEach`, you can use [`Array.some` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Alternately, you can use `Array.find` method:

```
eventBus.$on('answer-added', answer => {

    // Instead of using forEach, you can use Array.some() method
    const answerExists = this.answers.some((x) => e.id == answer.answer_id);

    if (!answerExists) {
      this.answers.push({
        id: answer.answer_id,
        answer: answer.answer_text
      });
    }
});
```

> Second, there is no problem with using an **event bus**, but it is generally used for a sibling or cross-component communication. When all the components are in the same ancestor or parent hierarchy, using `$emit` for events is the right way.

In your case, even though you have a nested components hierarchy, as the application evolves, a hierarchy can get really deep and you will quickly lose the track of typical **publish-subscribe** mechanism of the event bus. Even if it means re-emitting the same events from intermediate components, you should follow this practice.

Comment: So does that mean whenever the child component data changes I need to pass it back to the parent and run these checks against the array in the parent to create/update/delete the pertinent object? I thought Vue would have a better way of doing this... Anyway, thanks for the `Array.some()` and event bus tips, it does look cleaner.

Comment: @Albert, That is right. Most of the unidirectional data flow architecture based frameworks follow this style of event and props.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across with the same issue, the problem I encountered is resolved by using a [Simple Global Store](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch). Other more complex scenarios would possibly require [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) as suggested by @Dan above.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback from parent to child. Now they can communicate bottom up. The child can pass any data the parent might want and then the parent can take back control and use its state or closure state.